# Heroku launched paid plan but no customer center except for stackoverflow

Tags: heroku, stack-overflow

As of today my `Heroku` app is not running with this message.

```
2022-12-01T14:49:58.137993+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2022-12-02T04:24:16.047762+00:00 app[api]: Scaled to web@0:Eco by user api-maintenance@heroku.com
```

Looking at the notice, it says that you can upgrade to a paid plan.

However, no matter how much you look around, they do not operate a separate customer center. And they only direct me to this site.

I'm afraid that if I paid then only lost the money and couldn't get a refund.

Is there a customer center or other countermeasures that I don't know about?

Comment: Whatever Heroku might say, [we cannot provide customer service here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255745/354577). They don't get to decide what is on topic on Stack Overflow. Customer service questions _must_ go to the vendor in question. Can't you [contact them](https://www.heroku.com/support)?

Comment: (We _can_ help with programming questions related to Heroku. This message just says that your app has been scaled to zero dynos. If you're willing to pay for them, can't you just scale to 1 or more dynos?)